# Why solutions of $x^2 \left(\sqrt{1-y^2} \sin (x)-\sin (4 x)\right)+2 x y=0$ for $y$ are not verified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation
$$x^2 \left(\sqrt{1-y^2} \sin (x)-\sin (4 x)\right)+2 x y=0$$
for $x>0$ and $y$ real.

Solving this equation for $y$, by Mathematica, I obtain these two solutions:
$$y=\frac{\pm \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^4 \sin ^2(x) (-\cos (2 x))+x^4 \sin ^2(x) \cos (8 x)+8 x^2 \sin ^2(x)}+4 x \sin (4 x)}{2 \left(x^2 \sin ^2(x)+4\right)}$$

But, then when I substitute them in the original equation, it is not verified. Where I am doing wrong? And, if these solutions are wrong, how can I solve this equation to obtain $y$?

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Why do you want to solve for $y$? Tell us more. Do you look for derivative?

Comment: How have you checked the result? By hand or in Mathematica?

Comment: @Raffaele It is part of another problem, and I need to obtain $y$ from this equation.

Comment: @Novice By Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a form of solution that will make you understand why you have "extraneous" roots.

Simplifying by $x$ (possible because $x > 0$) and grouping the two terms having a $y$ on a same side:

$$\sqrt{1-y^2}x \sin x+2y=x \sin 4x$$

If you put to the square both sides (knowing that in this way you introduce artificial roots), you get:

$$(1-y^2)(x \sin x)^2+4y\sqrt{1-y^2}(x \sin x)+4y^2=x \sin 4x$$

Said otherwise, moving some terms RHS/LHS:

$$(1-y^2)(x \sin x)^2+4y^2-x \sin 4x= -4y\sqrt{1-y^2}(x \sin x)$$

Squaring once again (possibly introducing again superfluous roots), one gets a 4th degree equation in $y$, which in fact contains only terms in $Y=y^2$ ; therefore one gets a **quadratic equation** in variable $Y$.

Finally, when returning to $y$ variable, one should obtain solution(s) that should the same as the ones found by Mathematica (one can indeed observe, without having done the final calculation the characteristic form $\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{d}}{2a}$ of the solutions to a quadratic equation) with the same drawback of the presence of extraneous roots.

**But**, as said upwards, all the roots will not be roots of the initial equation (broadly saying, we have multiplied by 4 the number of roots).

Remark: the introduction of fictitious roots is explainable on a naive simple example: starting from equation $x=1$ which has a unique root (evidently), squaring it gives $x^2=1$ with two roots $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: I am surprised that the Mathematica solution you give hasn't a global square root over it (with my notations, what you give is (big) $Y$, but we need $y=\sqrt{Y}$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, my solution also has square root over it. I see it!

Answer (score 0):

Let the function $y$ returned by Mathematica for the positive root be denoted as $y_+(x)$, and $y_-(x)$ denote the negative root. The solution(s) in $y$ for a given $x$ for $$x^{2}\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2}}\sin\left(x\right)-\sin\left(4x\right)\right)+2xy=0$$

*will* be in $\{y_-(x), y_+(x)\}$. However, the problem is that the Mathematica solutions may *also* "cover" regions where it doesn't line up with the original equation. If Mathematica was completely perfect, it would also have indicated the intervals where each solution $\left(y_-(x) \text{ and } y_+(x)\right)$ was an actual solution to the equation.